# Importing Text File to Access Table - File Contains References to Entries of Another Table

Tags: ms-access, text, import

I have an Access 2016 database with 2 tables. (Note I've used a simple example to explain the issue.)

Tables - One 'Cars' and one 'Showroom'.

Lets assume I have 10 'Cars' defined in that table. One of the fields in this table is 'Car Name'. An example 'Car Name' could be BMW 330i.

I then want to import, from a Text File (delimiter '~') the content for the Showroom table.

I've already configured the Showroom table and one of its fields is 'Car List'. This field has a lookup to the rows of the 'Cars' table and the 'Car Name' field within it.

When I import my data for the 'Showrooms' table I get an 'Unparsable Record' for the 'Car List' entry.

I've tried importing in the following format:

ENTRY #~SHOWROOM~CAR LIST

1~Coventry~BMW 330i, BMW 330d

This causes the issue detailed above. I've tried with and without spaces between the comma separated list of cars names. 
If I manually define the 'Car List' field from the multiple select choice from the 'Cars' table and 'Car Name' field it defines correctly and when exported it either shows a numeric reference of a comma separated list of Cars.

How do I import data from a text file that bares reference to a linked field of another table in the database?

Answer (score 0):

This seems backwards. The showroom surely has many cars and a car could be in many showrooms? There is a Many To Many relationship which requires a joining table. It should be

```
ShowroomTable
   ShowroomID
   Showroom Name

CarTable
   CarID
   CarName
```

And then

```
CarInShowroom
    ShowroomID
    CarID
```

Comment: Thats a very fair comment. Sadly i chose a bad example seemingly to describe the scenario. Lets assume for this example that the cars in the showroom are unique. For example by their Registration number. Thus a car can only be in one showroom. Taking that into account any idea on the import problem - Thanks in Advance. Cheers,

Comment: What's the primary key fields of teh tables, are they autonumber?